# Social logins (Signing up with LinkedIn)

Tags: php, rest, yii2, linkedin-api

I'm a little confused by some of what I'm reading and taking from articles on social logins and wanted some guidance. There seems to be a lot of social login examples or videos for Twitter + Facebook but not so much for LinkedIn.

I'm working through the sign in with LinkedIn pages using the REST API https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

It talks when requesting the authorization code of the state to stop CSRF. If you're redirecting a user to the LinkedIn Oauth page *presumably* with a link thats within the HTML, won't that just make the token visible to anyone anyway as this call is within the browser?

When it goes on to talk about refreshing tokens and redoing this process, it now reads to me that this is for literal signing in and nothing more? I was hoping that I could allow a user to connect/sign up to my website through the LinkedIn API (as an alternative to my website sign up form). Is that possible? I'm then unsure as to how things like logging in would be done if you signed up through LinkedIn. The system would need a user record for them in my DB to be able to create posts/topics etc.

I've really struggled to find concrete examples of how to implement this with LinkedIn so any help would be nice

Comment: Far as I can tell, the most important thing here is to protect your authentication keys. I'm sure they've taken into account about the HTML. I doubt they would leave anyone vulnerable.